# SAS: Passing in Array Names

Tags: sas

I'm working on code that will change the coding of several hundred variables stored as 1/0 or Y/N in numeric 1 or 0. Because this will need to be in a flexible process, I am writing a macro to do so. The only issue that I am have with the macro is I am unable to pass the SAS column names to the macro to work. Thoughts?

```
%Macro Test(S,E);
%Array(A,&S.-&E.);
%MEnd;

data subset;
    set dataset);
    %Test(v1,v20)
run;
```

Comment: I'd recommend using a proc sql; select into statement, building up your datastep array statements from it.  This method would be slow.  But you should be posting this to the Stack Exchange forum, not here, since your question does not contain any statistical question.

Answer (score 1):

SAS supports variable lists. Macro parameters are just text strings. So as long as you use the macro variable value in a place where SAS supports variable lists there is no problem passing a variable list to a macro.  For example here a simplistic macro to make an array statement.

```
%macro array(name,varlist);
  array &name &varlist ;
%mend;
```

Which you could then use in the middle of a data step like this.

```
data want;
  set have ;
  %array(binary,var1-var20 a--d male education);
  do over binary; binary=binary in ('Y','1','T'); end;
run;
```

The difficult part is if you want to convert variables from character to numeric then you will need to rename them.  This will make it difficult to use variable lists (x1-x5 or vara -- vard).  You can solve that problem with a little extra logic to convert the variable lists into a list of individual names.  For example you can use PROC TRANSPOSE to create a dataset with the variable names that match your list.

```
proc transpose data=&inds(obs=0) out=_names ;
  var &varlist;
run;
```

You could then use this dataset to generate code or generate a list of the individual variable names.

```
proc sql noprint ;
  select name into :varlist2 separated by ' ' from _names;
quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

A list of all variable names is stored in the dictionary.columns dataset. You can access it and store the names as a list that you can then loop through:

```
proc sql noprint;
    select name into: list_of_names
    separated by " "
    from dictionary.columns where memname = upcase("your_dataset");
quit;
%put &list_of_names.;
```